# USB Problems after installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

So I decided to go ahead and install Ubuntu, and dual boot Linux Mint too.
However, after I installed both of them, I connected the USB to my windows 7 (Other PC) and the size was 2.17 mb out of 2.17 mb.
I moved what was inside and formatted it, and then I had an message:

```
In order to use this device you need to format it.
```

So I tried formatting it(again), and this time it said it failed.
I inserted it back into Ubuntu, went to 'disks', and I see it there.
Here are the details about the USB:

```
Model: SanDisk Curzor Pop (1.27)
Size: 8 GB
Partitioning: Master Boot Record
Seriel Number: 4C530009360418115380

Volumes:
*Free space: 8GB*
Size: 8 GB
Device: /dev/usb
Contents: Unallocated Space
```

I went ahead and installed GParted Partition Editor, and I couldn't find `/dev/sdb`, all I see is:

```
/dev/sda1 | File System: ext4 | Size: 237.05 GiB | Unused: 223.47 GiB | Flags: boot

/dev/sda2 | File System: extended | Size: 228.71 GiB | Unused: *none* GiB | Flags: *none* 

/dev/sda6 | File System: ext4 | Size: 244.89 GiB | Unused: 212.64 GB | Flags:
*none* 

/dev/sda5 | File System: linux swap | Size: 3.82 GiB | Unused: 3.82 GiB | Flags: *none* 

unallocated | File System: unallocated | Size: 1.02 MiB | Unused: *none* | Flags: *none*
```

For those who wonder what was in the USB before I first formatted it(when it was 2.17MB)
This is what was there:
folder: efi
inside efi: folder boot
inside boot: bootx64.efi
inside boot: grubx64.efi

I Can't find `/dev/sdb`, but I can see the Hard Drive in 'Disks'
What should I do?

Comment: Please plug in your USB drive and after 10–30 seconds run `sudo dmesg | head -n 20` and `sudo lsblk -f` and post their output here. You might also want to try different USB ports on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

On GParted, you wanna click this button:
[image: And select /dev/sdb]

And select /dev/sdb. If it isn't there, then your USB may be broken.

Comment: The partitions in /dev/sda here are not needed, i took this from a image of GParted.